# 5V Device Open Collector with 3.3V Controller

Tags: microcontroller, open-collector

I am new to electronics being a mechanical engineer.

My question is this: I am about to use an Allegro A314x Hall Sensor, powered by 5V. Datasheet ([link](https://www.elecrow.com/download/A3141-2-3-4-Datasheet.pdf)) says, data pin is **open collector**.

I want to use the data signal with a micro controller operating at 3.3 V, max 3.6 V allowed.

Do I understand **open collector** correct in the sense, that I can pull-(up) (R 10k) the data pin to 3.3 V and will not have to fear damaging the micro controller?

If not, what do you suggest to prevent damage on the micro controller?

EDIT: added link to datasheet

Comment: That's probably sound, though I didn't look at the Hall sensor you mentioned to see if it is high side or low side. But assuming low side, then a pull up makes sense and the value you selected isn't unusual, at all. It should work in most cases. But I also don't know about the environment all this operates in. You are worried about damage. Is it just about the supply rail voltage exceeding the MCU limits? Or are their environmental issues that also need attention, as well? (Accidental screwdriver across pin, etc.)

Comment: @dexamenos Post a link to the datasheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Source: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/open-collector-outputs.html

Open collectors are useful because the allow the user to decide what Vcc is.

If the transistor is on, then it pulls down Vout to Vce of the transistor (logic 0 for most inputs).

If the transistor is off then Vout goes to near Vcc (or V+) in the diagram.

This means you can set Vcc to 3.3V (or whatever value you want) and it won't damage the micro-controller because it won't be able to go beyond 3.3V

Comment: Or open drain.  For the purposes of using an output pin on a device, "Open collector" means pretty much the same thing as "open drain", it's just that the former implies an NPN bipolar junction transistor, while the latter implies an N-channel field effect transistor.

Comment: Your answer could be a bit more explicit about how the "+V" node in the diagram can be completely independent of the Vcc/Vdd supply for the chip with the open collector/open drain output.

Comment: I think the diagram shows that well

Comment: The explanation for why Vcc will never exceed 3.3V needs an explanation. You mention Vce, but it's not labeled in the diagram, nor explained. +V label adds little to the explanation and is the same thing as Vcc.